# Returning GET content inside POST Payload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am doing a POST through an Ajax call with its post variables (data)
.
Everything goes fine until I noticed in the Request Payload is brining the GET contet as if would be calling GET explicitly I don not know why is this happen because in my API structure

I am veryfing with:

```
if (isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && ( strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === strtolower($handler_method)) ) {
    //do task
}
```

here the handler method is the method set that will handle the task
Any ideas?

NOTE: The ajax call is made through Backbone because if I do this in JQuery Ajax it works normally without brining any GET content.

**NOTE: The GET content are comming inside the Request Payload as I mentionted, the JSON results are ok:
 {data: null, report: "NO_PARAMS_WRONG_DATA_TYPE", success: false}**

Comment: could you supply a snippet of your javascript code?

Comment: Have you checked the AJAX operation via an AJAX viewer in your browser? If it's the server side that's the problem (i.e. the output of the AJAX call) then add some debugging to the JSON-encoded reply, so you can narrow down the problem. At the moment though I don't think your question has enough detail to help us assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely that you are missing to set type of request when doing ajax call.
Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for settings -> type:

> type (default: 'GET')
>
> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET".

So, you should do:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   type:'POST',
    ...
})
```

in order to force jquery send POST request

> I am doing a POST through an Ajax call with its post variables (data)

Simply using `data` you will not get POST request, as `data` is used for both GET and POST requests. Just encoded in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

$_REQUEST includes all the variables of $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIES. If you only want $_POST, then use $_POST.